# Regex to match everything except image name and extension

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this regex
 `((?:https?\:\/\/)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}(?:[\w\-]+\.)+(?:[\w]{2,5}))(?:\:[\d]{1,5})?\/(?:[^\s\/]+\/)*(?:[^\s]+\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|PNG|JPE?G|GIF|SVG))(?:\?\w+=\w+(?:&\w+=\w+)*)?)`

to select these image urls from a string

`http://my.a.example.com/kf/urjlsjjsXVXXq6xXFXXX6/20jaa/jajc1agiCJFXXXXb8XVXXq6xXFXXX6.jpg?size=158385&height=79&width=50&hash=13e12eaa837ae8341e35cbde5ea544a`

`https://example.com/imhgegg.png`

What I wanted is to match everything except `jajc1agiCJFXXXXb8XVXXq6xXFXXX6.jpg` and `mhgegg.png` ie image name and extension.

Please can that be achieved?

### EDIT

I actually get this link from a json file I fetch online.
What I really want to do is :

```
String regex; //regex to match everything except image name and extension.
String imageName = IMAGEURL.replaceAll(regex, "")
```

So if I log `imageName`, I want to get `jajc1agiCJFXXXXb8XVXXq6xXFXXX6.jpg` and `mhgegg.png`

Comment: Is it just the image path you want (without the file name)? If so you don't need regex for that. You could just do: String fileURL = urlString.substring(0, urlString.lastIndexOf("/"));

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thanks. But what will happen to characters after the image extension?

Comment: Yes...they would not be collected. I see. You want everything before and after the file name.

Comment: @DevilsHnd exactly!

Comment: Can you post a relevant part of the source text  so we have a better idea how the urls are put in it.

Comment: @greenapps I have edited my question

Comment: You did not post a source text. And your post is very confusing as only at the end it is clear what you want: extracting image names. Not urls or so. You should have told your goal at the beginning of your post first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you just don't care whether or not you use RegEx:

**Required imports:**

```
import java.io.File
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
```

The code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://my.a.example.com/kf/urjlsjjsXVXXq6xXFXXX6/20jaa/jajc1agiCJFXXXXb8XVXXq6xXFXXX6.jpg?size=158385&height=79&width=50&hash=13e12eaa837ae8341e35cbde5ea544a");

try {
    String fileName = new File(url.getPath()).getName();
    String urlWithNoFileName = url.toString().replace(fileName, "");
    System.out.println("File Name within URL is: " + fileName);
    System.out.println("URL with File Name removed:\n" + urlWithNoFileName);
} 
catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    //Do what you want with Exception.
}
```

A bit more overhead but it does work and it works for file names with no extension.

Comment: Thanks your answer nicked it!

Answer (score 0):

yes check this:

```
(?!.*mhgegg\.png.*)(?!.*jajc1agiCJFXXXXb8XVXXq6xXFXXX6\.jpg.*)((?:https?\:\/\/)(?:[a-zA-Z]{1}(?:[\w\-]+\.)+(?:[\w]{2,5}))(?:\:[\d]{1,5})?\/(?:[^\s\/]+\/)*(?:[^\s]+\.(?:png|jpe?g|gif|svg|PNG|JPE?G|GIF|SVG))(?:\?\w+=\w+(?:&\w+=\w+)*)?)
```

using this all the things you want will be accepted except the string includes "mhgegg.png" and "jajc1agiCJFXXXXb8XVXXq6xXFXXX6.jpg" in any part of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the images urls are dynamic so your code's gonna work